# Why do USB connectors have 2 square holes?

Tags: usb, connector

Almost every USB connector I've seen so far looks like a robot. Is this design required, and if so, why?

[image: usb]

Comment: because your brain is wired to detect faces

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming it's not a joke question and you're speaking about those square holes, they're there to interlock with spring-loaded tabs on the other part of USB connector. They make it so that some force is required to pull out the connector and it doesn't fall out by itself.

Comment: that was not a joke question and i don't know why people downvoted, and yes i wanted to learn the purpose of those square holes. And in my question I was mentioned that i am actually talking about these square holes but then someone edited my question and deleted it, and it looked like a joke question....  https://imgur.com/eR4Cbf1

unbelievable...

Comment: also, if this is the case, then why type-c plugs are not designed like this?

Comment: Type-C has similar idea with springy tabs and detents but they're hidden on the inside.

Comment: Also, Micro-USB has kind of "hooks" on the plug and slots on the receiving side for this same purpose.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: [Digi-Key](https://www.digikey.ie/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/1903814-1/2286683?utm_adgroup=&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=PMax_Shopping_Zombie%20SKUs&utm_term=&productid=2286683&gclid=CjwKCAiA2L-dBhACEiwAu8Q9YH1hmRLcq_GVStU4Gw93w7eCLYscx4Dkxqbh8lTATfDG0KVBMgwgnRoCTiYQAvD_BwE).*

- Obviously the robot needs four legs for V+, Data+, Data- and GND.
- There are square holes on both sides of the Type A plug. One set holds the insert in place. The other accepts the spring grips shown in Figure 1. If you insert a USB plug slowly into a receptacle you should be able to feel it get pulled in by the springs.
- The case is pressed out of sheet metal so it has to be folded and joined at some point. One or two dovetails make sure that the case won't split. The join line may be determined by the USB standard so that it gives a visual clue as to which way is up. (Normally we use the USB logo to determine this but the logo can only be used under licence. Also the join line won't wear away with use!)

Interestingly the connectors are quite expensive at €2.47 for one, dropping to €1.28 for 2,450. I would have expected about one tenth of that price given how long we've been making these and how many billions must have be manufactured by now.

Comment: yeah, digikey is however kind of the jewelery store of data connectors for some reason. Other, often smaller, distributors, beat them in price regularly, e.g. [TME](https://www.tme.eu/de/en/katalog/usb-ieee1394-connectors/0185856542e402eec8800ad7a8c96560.html)

Answer (score 3):

The design is (mostly) standardised and based on functionality, so they all look mostly the same. This helps them fit where they are supposed to go.

*Any resemblance to real robots or other real-life entities is purely coincidental.*